# Executing a SQL query in string format

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a query in quotes(' '). I want Oracle SQL to not to treat as string but as a query and store the data from the query in a variable.

Here I am trying to store the date in array - example:

```
[10-JAN-22 01.47,10-JAN-22 01.47]
```

which is a string by the way

Code is here

```
DECLARE qms varchar(400);

BEGIN
    qms := 'select ''['' || TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ''DD-MON-RR HH.MI'') || '',''|| TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ''DD-MON-RR HH.MI'') || '']'' as customdate from dual';
    dbms_output.put_line('value of varl is ' ||qms);
END;
```

Here is the output

```
value of varl is select '[' || TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI') || ','|| TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI') || ']' as customdate from dual
```

I need to get the data from query but here the query is getting printed.

I am newbie and just learning SQL - any help would be appreciated

Comment: As a side observation, why why why why why WHY are you using 2-digt years?  All you are doing is re-creating the Y2K issue.   And the RR mask was meant to be a _temporary_ band-aid solution to buy some time back in 1998, 1999.  All it really did was kick the can down the road, as a lot of people discovered - to their dismay - around 1-JAN-2020.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need **dynamic SQL** for that:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2     qms    VARCHAR (400);
  3     l_res  VARCHAR2 (50);
  4  BEGIN
  5     qms :=
  6        'select ''['' || TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ''DD-MON-RR HH.MI'') || '',''|| TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ''DD-MON-RR HH.MI'') || '']'' as customdate from dual';
  7
  8     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE qms
  9        INTO l_res;
 10
 11     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('value of varl is ' || l_res);
 12  END;
 13  /
value of varl is [10-SIJ-22 10.12,10-SIJ-22 10.12]

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```